# Simplest way to turn 32 bit array into 8 bit array C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c

I'm sure this question has been asked several times but I wasn't able to find a satisfying answer.

I'm looking for an elegant/clean way to turn a 32-bit array into a longer 8-bit array

For example, let's say I have an embedded device that reads from its flash memory in 32-bit blocks, but I would like to turn 4 of those 32-bit blocks into 16 separate 8-bit blocks. Essentially I am just converting a 32-bit array into a longer 8-bit array

My current idea is that for each element in the 32-bit array I would simply bit shift it to line up with each equivalent element in the 8-bit array, like this:

```c
bit8[0] = bit32[0];
bit8[1] = bit32[0] >> 8;
bit8[2] = bit32[0] >> 16;
bit8[3] = bit32[0] >> 24;

bit8[4] = bit32[1];
bit8[5] = bit32[1] >> 8;
bit8[6] = bit32[1] >> 16;
bit8[7] = bit32[1] >> 24;

bit8[8] = bit32[2];
bit8[9] = bit32[2] >> 8;
bit8[10] = bit32[2] >> 16;
bit8[11] = bit32[2] >> 24;

bit8[12] = bit32[3];
bit8[13] = bit32[3] >> 8;
bit8[14] = bit32[3] >> 16;
bit8[15] = bit32[3] >> 24;
```

Now I *could* do the same thing with a loop, but something about it just looks messy to me, and besides if this was on an embedded device (which is where I've run into this type of issue usually) speed can make a big difference, and this would be a little slower than just doing it explicitly like above.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        bit8[(i*4)]   = bit32[i];
        bit8[(i*4)+1] = bit32[i] >> 8;
        bit8[(i*4)+2] = bit32[i] >> 16;
        bit8[(i*4)+3] = bit32[i] >> 24; 
    }
```

This method is also entirely platform dependent. So I'm wondering if there's an elegant/clean method for doing this, bonus if its platform *in*dependent

Comment: You're explicitly copying these bytes as little-endian. If the bytes are already in the same endianness as your platform, then a straight `memcpy` will suffice. A single call will copy the entire array. _e.g._ `memcpy(bit8, bit32, sizeof(bit8));`

Comment: Note that if the compiler sees a performance advantage, and you've elected to compile for performance and not size, it'll probably unroll the loop.

Comment: This feels like an xy problem. But I think the best way is to just write a function that allows you to edit the chunk you want, whatever the sizes involved

Comment: One other thing to note it's legal to access the bytes of the `bit32` array directly: `char *bytes = (char*)bit32;` -- note that the reverse is not true (accessing a char array as 32-bit values violates strict aliasing). So here, potentially no copy is required.

Comment: platypushunter, If you are serious about speed, rather than micro-optimized, post code that shows the larger access/speed issue.

Comment: I guess it depends on the compiler.  All the ones I randomly picked at godbolt.org generate the same exact code at -03

Comment: @paddy `char` is always the wrong type to use for raw data due to the implementation-defined signedness. Use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what's stored there. If it is integers, then it is endianess-dependent and then it might matter if the first byte of each 32 bit chunk gets copied into index 0 or 3.

If it's just raw data, then your shift method works. But then there's no need for an array at all. Assuming `uint8_t` is a character type (pretty much always the case), then simply do:

```
uint8_t* bit8 = (uint8_t*)bit32;
```

You can always break down a larger type in C into a bytes by using a character type (but not the other way around).